# Express the system : $x'=y-x^3, y'=-x +y^3$ via polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, nonlinear-system

I have trouble expressing the following system via polar coordinates :

> \begin{cases} x'=y-x^3 \\y'= -x + y^3\end{cases}

so for :

$$\begin{cases} x=r\cosθ \\ y=r\sinθ \end{cases}$$

we get :

$$\begin{cases} (r\cosθ)' = r\sinθ - r^3\cos^3θ \\  (r\sinθ)' = -r\cosθ + r^3\sin^3θ \end{cases}$$

My problem here is, I don't know how to calculate the expressions $(r\cosθ)'$ and $(r\sinθ)'$, since the differentation was carried out with respect to $x$ and $y$.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with finalising the expression to polar coordinates.

Comment: What is $x'$ ? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 $$\frac{dx}{dy}$$

Comment: Are you sure its not the derivative with respect to time ?

Comment: @Sou燈馬想 It probably is with respect to time, if I'm mistaken. In the end, the solutions $x(t)$,$y(t)$ should be with respect to time. In this case, how do I proceed ?

Comment: Just use leibniz rule $(r \cos \theta)' = (r' \cos \theta + r (\cos \theta)')$. Because r and $\theta$ must be function of time too.

Comment: @Moo Thanks for the great post recommendation, really helpful ! Yep, this is what I got !

Comment: @Moo By the way, in this case, can I make any conclusion about the sign of $r'$ ? To me, it seems that since $r>0$ then $-r^3 <0$ and we'll have periodic changes to the sign of $r'$ for different $θ$.

Comment: @Moo Well, yeah, there's a periodic change of sign which is logical, since we have $\cos$ and $\sin$ in the expressions, which means that the sign of $r'$ will also periodically change. Thanks for the graph !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have by product rule and chain rule:
$$
\begin{split}
x' &= \frac{dx}{dt}
   &= \frac{d[r\cos \theta]}{dt}
   &= \frac{dr}{dt} \cos \theta + r \frac{d[\cos \theta]}{dt}
   &= \frac{dr}{dt} \cos \theta - r \sin \theta \frac{d\theta}{dt}
\end{split}
$$
and you can use the same for $y'$.